# Two subjects that are inextricably linked/bonded together

Tags: phrases, terminology

I'm doing a piece where I am trying to state that a place is linked/bonded together with a river tightly. Just using "linked/bonded" as a term seems weak,  is there any phrase to replace them that showcases that the two subjects have to be together, that each individual may fail if separated.

Comment: Give an example sentence with a dash in which you are going to use the word.

Comment: 'Inextricably associated with' is the usual term

Answer (score 1):

Two options are **yoked** and **entwined**.

From Merriam-Webster:

> [entwined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entwined): To become twisted together or around
>
> Example: *Now a new documentary will look at the history of this genre, in which the pastoral is routinely* entwined *with the painful.*

---

> [yoked](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yoked): to join as if by a yoke

Example using the place/river:

- *The place is yoked to the river.*
- *The place is entwined with the river.*

Answer (score 0):

You could try **inseparable** and remove the tightly at the end as it already denotes strong relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The two entities are **[intertwined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intertwine)**. Then again, your use of "inextricable" encapsulates the idea you are going for, I feel (as @Edwin Ashworth mentionned) .

> **intertwine**
>   [ˌin(t)ərˈtwīn]
>   VERB
>   intertwined (past tense) · intertwined (past participle)
>
> twist or twine together.
>
> *"a net made of cotton intertwined with other natural fibers"* · *"the coils intertwine with one another like strands of spaghetti"* · *"Dickens has been very clever to intertwine all these aspects and ideas"*